# Angular JS + Node JS + Passport + Spring OAuth2 Authentication/Authorization

Tags: angularjs, node.js, spring-security, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I am new to PassportJS and AngularJS and I have a doubt about how to proceed with this authorization.

I have Spring REST API Secured by Oauth2, but I have to send together user credentials like this:

```
[http://localhost:8080/myapp/oauth/token]
grant_type=password&username=email&password=password&client_id=09e749d8309f4044&client_secret=189309492722aa5a&scope=read
```

In client my application I use passport and I want to authorize/authenticate my users, how can I create a Stratagy for this ?

I will send here my server config and my security Lib.

Server.js

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    var http = require('http');
    var https = require('https');
    var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/cert/privatekey.pem').toString();
    var certificate = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/cert/certificate.pem').toString();
    var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};

    var express = require('express');
    var config = require('./config.js');
    var passport = require('passport');
    var security = require('./lib/security');
    var xsrf = require('./lib/xsrf');
    var protectJSON = require('./lib/protectJSON');
    require('express-namespace');

    var app = express();
    var secureServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
    var server = http.createServer(app);

    // Serve up the favicon
    app.use(express.favicon(config.server.distFolder + '/favicon.ico'));

    // First looks for a static file: index.html, css, images, etc.
    app.use(config.server.staticUrl, express.compress());
    app.use(config.server.staticUrl, express['static'](config.server.distFolder));
    app.use(config.server.staticUrl, function(req, res, next) {
      res.send(404); // If we get here then the request for a static file is invalid
    });

    app.use(protectJSON);

    app.use(express.logger());                                  // Log requests to the console
    app.use(express.bodyParser());                              // Extract the data from the body of the request - this is needed by the LocalStrategy authenticate method
    app.use(express.cookieParser(config.server.cookieSecret));  // Hash cookies with this secret
    app.use(express.cookieSession());                           // Store the session in the (secret) cookie
    app.use(passport.initialize());                             // Initialize PassportJS
    app.use(passport.session());                                // Use Passport's session authentication strategy - this stores the logged in user in the session and will now run on any request
    app.use(xsrf);                                              // Add XSRF checks to the request
    security.initialize(config.oauth.authorize_url, config.oauth.access_token, config.oauth.apiKey, config.oauth.secretKey, config.oauth.scopereq);           // Add a Oauth strategy for handling the authentication

    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      if ( req.user ) {
        console.log('Current User:', req.user.firstName, req.user.lastName);
      } else {
        console.log('Unauthenticated');
      }
      next();
    });

    app.post('/login', security.login);
    app.post('/logout', security.logout);

    // Retrieve the current user
    app.get('/current-user', security.sendCurrentUser);

    // Retrieve the current user only if they are authenticated
    app.get('/authenticated-user', function(req, res) {
      security.authenticationRequired(req, res, function() { security.sendCurrentUser(req, res); });
    });

    // Retrieve the current user only if they are admin
    app.get('/admin-user', function(req, res) {
      security.adminRequired(req, res, function() { security.sendCurrentUser(req, res); });
    });

    // This route deals enables HTML5Mode by forwarding missing files to the index.html
    app.all('/*', function(req, res) {
      // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
      res.sendfile('index.html', { root: config.server.distFolder });
    });

    // A standard error handler - it picks up any left over errors and returns a nicely formatted server 500 error
    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));

    // Start up the server on the port specified in the config
    server.listen(config.server.listenPort, 'localhost', 511, function() {
      // // Once the server is listening we automatically open up a browser
      var open = require('open');
      open('http://localhost:' + config.server.listenPort + '/');
    });
    console.log('Deengo Business App Server - listening on port: ' + config.server.listenPort);
    secureServer.listen(config.server.securePort);
    console.log('Deengo Business App Server - listening on secure port: ' + config.server.securePort);
```

lib/security.js

```
    var express = require('express');
    var passport = require('passport');
    var app = express();
    var BearerStrategy = require('passport-http-bearer').Strategy

    var filterUser = function(user) {
      if ( user ) {
        return {
          user : {
            id: user._id.$oid,
            email: user.email,
            firstName: user.firstName,
            lastName: user.lastName,
            admin: user.admin
          }
        };
      } else {
        return { user: null };
      }
    };

    var security = {
      initialize: function(_authorize_url, _access_token, _apiKey, _secretKey, _scopereq) {
        passport.use('deengo-auth', new OAuth2Strategy({
            authorizationURL: _authorize_url,
            tokenURL: _access_token,
            clientID: _apiKey,
            clientSecret: _secretKey,
            callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/oauth/autorize/callback',
            scope: _scopereq,
            passReqToCallback: true,
            skipUserProfile: true        
          },
          function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            client['headers']['authorization'] = 'bearer ' + req.session.passport.accessToken;        
            User.findOrCreate({ clientId: clientId }, function(err, user) {
              done(err, user);
            });
          }
        ));

      },
      authenticationRequired: function(req, res, next) {
        console.log('authRequired');
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
          next();
        } else {
          res.json(401, filterUser(req.user));
        }
      },
      adminRequired: function(req, res, next) {
        console.log('adminRequired');
        if (req.user && req.user.admin ) {
          next();
        } else {
          res.json(401, filterUser(req.user));
        }
      },
      sendCurrentUser: function(req, res, next) {
        res.json(200, filterUser(req.user));
        res.end();
      },
      login: function(req, res, next) {

        console.log(req.body.email);
        console.log(req.body.password);

        function authenticationFailed(err, user, info){

          //if (err) { return next(err); }
          /*if (!user) { return res.json(filterUser(user)); }
          req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if ( err ) { return next(err); }
            return res.json(filterUser(user));
          });*/
        }
        //passport.authenticate("deengo-auth", authenticationFailed)(req, res, next);
        return null;
      },
      logout: function(req, res, next) {
        req.logout();
        res.send(204);
      }
    };

    module.exports = security;
```

lib/DeengoStrategy.js

```
 

    var util = require('util');
    var passport = require('passport');
    var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
    var BearerStrategy = require('passport-http-bearer').Strategy;
    var rest = require('request');

    function DeengoRestStrategy(authorize_url, access_token, apiKey, secretKey, scopereq) {
      this.authorize_url = authorize_url;
      this.access_token = access_token;
      this.apiKey = apiKey;
      this.secretKey = secretKey;
      this.scopereq = secretKey;
      this.baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/deengo/api/';

      // Call the super constructor - passing in our user verification function
      // We use the email field for the username
      LocalStrategy.call(this, { usernameField: 'email' }, this.verifyUser.bind(this));

      // Serialize the user into a string (id) for storing in the session
      passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id); 
      });

      // Deserialize the user from a string (id) into a user (via a cll to REST)
      passport.deserializeUser(this.get.bind(this));

      // We want this strategy to have a nice name for use by passport, e.g. app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('deengo'));
      this.name = DeengoRestStrategy.name;
    }

    // DeengoRestStrategy inherits from LocalStrategy
    util.inherits(DeengoRestStrategy, LocalStrategy);

    DeengoRestStrategy.name = "deengo";

    // Query the users collection
    DeengoRestStrategy.prototype.query = function(query, done) {
      query.accessToken = this.accessToken;     // Add the apiKey to the passed in query
      var request = rest.get(this.baseUrl, { qs: query, json: {} }, function(err, response, body) {
        done(err, body);
      });
    };

    // Get a user by id
    DeengoRestStrategy.prototype.get = function(id, done) {
      var query = { apiKey: this.apiKey };
      var request = rest.get(this.baseUrl + id, { qs: query, json: {} }, function(err, response, body) {
        done(err, body);
      });
    };

    // Find a user by their email
    DeengoRestStrategy.prototype.findByEmail = function(email, done) {
      this.query({ q: JSON.stringify({email: email}) }, function(err, result) {
        if ( result && result.length === 1 ) {
          return done(err, result[0]);
        }
        done(err, null);
      });
    };

    // Check whether the user passed in is a valid one
    DeengoRestStrategy.prototype.verifyUser = function(email, password, done) {
      this.findByEmail(email, function(err, user) {
        if (!err && user) {
          if (user.password !== password) {
            user = null;
          }
        }
        done(err, user);
      });
    };

    module.exports = DeengoRestStrategy;
```

I do not know if I have to use passport-Bearer or not and how to use-it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards,

Eduardo.

Comment: For the OAuth2 part, I assume you have seen: https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize/tree/master/examples/express2

Comment: Sorry, disregard my comment, I miss read, my link is for the OAuth2 server which you already have and want to connect to. I'm not at the client yet.

Comment: Here's an example app using everyauth: https://github.com/ganarajpr/express-angular

Comment: I'm not sure how this is an Angular question...

Answer (score 7):

> I do not know if I have to use passport-Bearer or not and how to use-it.

No. There are other options, such as:

- [oauth.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218293/1113772)
- [httpProvider + express middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18219943/1113772)

Here is an example of how to use passport:

```
// Express using passport-local
// This code is adaptation of examples/express3 from https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local


// configure Express
app.configure(function() {
// ...
app.use(express.session({
// The domain should start with a dot, as this allows the subdomain.
domain: '.app.local',
secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));

// Enable cors.
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
next();
});

// ...
});

app.get('/account', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
// Return the current user's info
res.json(req.user);
});
```

**References**

- [Express + AngularJS Subdomain login](https://gist.github.com/amitaibu/6573250)