# Angular issues and "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header" - Using OAuth 2, Passport, Express and Node

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, cors, passport.js

I have a web application that uses OAuth 2 running on Node.  Using EJS templates I was able to properly create a workflow that prompts a user to login, authenticate, and then performs a "GetUser" GET command and dumps the output to the screen.  Recently I have attempted to remove EJS and want to get AnguarJS working.

Currently I have removed EJS and implemented Angular, however with angular many strange things happen and I cannot figure out why!

When my user clicks "Login" they are supposed to be brought to another website that they login to using OAuth 2.  This process works fine on Node with EJS, however with angular my controller loads, the correct partial is loaded but there is no data.  Reviewing this process with Chrome DEV tools I see the following error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://website/oauth/authorize?... 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'     
header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

What is even weirder is that in the network tab I can see the correct Request URL!  If I copy and paste this URL into another tab my "GetUser" command executes, but then node crashes and my page fails.

I have attempted different browsers, enabling CORS, and configuring CORS.  I know the issue is with Angular as I can successfully use the same code with EJS.  I have put my Angular code below, any assistance would be appreciated!

## Server Side

### app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var config = require('./config.js')
var passport = require('passport');
var OAuth2Strategy = require('passport-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
var session = require('express-session');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var login = require('./routes/login');
var logout = require('./routes/logout');

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {done(null, obj);
});

// config
passport.use('Company', new OAuth2Strategy({
    authorizationURL: config.authorizationURL,
    tokenURL: config.tokenURL,
    clientID: config.clientID,
    clientSecret: config.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: config.callbackURL,
    passReqToCallback: true
},
function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    process.nextTick(function () {
        // store access token
        req.session.accessToken=accessToken;
        return done(null, profile);
    });
}
));

var app = express();
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session({secret: 'secret'}))
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// configure Express
app.get('/api/login', ensureAuthenticated, login.execute);
app.get('/api/logout', logout.execute);

app.get('/auth/company', 
passport.authenticate('company'), 
 function(req, res){
});

app.get('/auth/company/callback',
passport.authenticate('company', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
function(req, res) {
 console.log('comming back from company');   
 res.redirect('/api/login');
}); 


app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
   if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
    }
    res.redirect('/')
}

module.exports = app;
```

### Login.js (Route)

```
var request = require('request');

exports.execute = function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.user);
    console.log(req.app.get('accessToken'));

    var accessToken = req.session.accessToken;
    console.log("accessToken in loginjs" + accessToken);
    if(accessToken){
        var options = {
        url: 'http://company/getCurrentUser',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'bearer ' + accessToken
        }
        };
        request.get(options, function(error, response, body){
            if(error){
               console.log('login.js inside error' + error);
               res.json('login.js inside error' + error);
        return;
            }
            console.log(response);
            res.render('account', { user: response });
        });
    }else{
        res.render('account', { user: req.user });
    }   
}
```

### www

```
var debug = require('debug')('myApp');
var app = require('../app');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

## Client Side

### app.js (angular)##

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ngMessages', 'ngRoute', 'mgcrea.ngStrap'])
.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'views/account.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    })      
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    }); 
}]);
```

### login.js Controller

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', 'Auth', function($scope, Auth){
    var user = Auth.authorize();
    $scope.user=user;
    $scope.headingTitle='Logged in page';
}]);
```

### auth.js Service

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.factory('Auth', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('/auth/company', null, 
    {
        'authorize': {method: 'GET'}
    });
}]);
```

### home.html Partial to route to company Oauth2

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="text-center">
        <p><a href="/login">Login via Company</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### account.html Partial to show User data

```
<div>
  <h1>You are logged in.</h1>
  <a href="/">Go home</a><br>
  <a href="/api/logout">Logout</a><br>
  <p>Dumping User: {{user}}</p>
</div>
```

#### edit

I have tried the follow with no success

```
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-     Requested-With, Access-Control-Allow-Origin');
    res.header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400"); // 24 hours
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.send(200);
    }
    else {
        next();
   }
};
var app = express();
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

### Edit 2:

I did some more digging and also noticed that Angular is not listed as initiating the second URL.  Its almost as if angular is re-routing the callback URL as a separate call of its own.  I have attached the below picture
[image: Dev Tools for Chrome of returned calls]

### Edit 3:

I have continued to work on this but cannot figure out why Angular is stripping out my headers!  Any Additional input would be greatly appreciated!

### Edit 4:

I found that I can have the webpage load the route instead of Angular by adding the code below to the Login button.  After doing this and pointing the link to /auth/company rather than to api/login I get successfully redirected to the login page!

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="text-center">
        <p><a target="_self" href="/auth/company">Login via Company</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However the battle continues, as after I login I get redirected to the below picture - inside of node I receive the data however the application dies and does not show the /account page.
[image: Page after coming back from Oauth 2 Authentication]

Comment: Possible Duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors-in-express-nodejs/7069902#7069902
Try the third answer, quickest solution. Read the whole thing to understand it.

Comment: I have added and edit above - I have give this a try but saw the same result

Comment: I have continued to make edits but I still cannot find a solution to my issue!  Angular is taking over in some aspects I haven't gotten my head around yet I guess!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular JS + Node JS + Passport + Spring OAuth2 Authentication/Authorization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18260230/angular-js-node-js-passport-spring-oauth2-authentication-authorization)

Comment: @Kent0111 have you solve this problem ? because I have the same issue.

Comment: I never got this resolved no.  I ended up programming out with EJS and injecting Anguar into the page.

I have been meaning to re-visit this project but I have not yet had the time!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try enabling CORS in express server

```
npm install cors
```

app.js

```
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

Reference to [this link](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

Answer (score 0):

I never user `$resource` and instead use `$http`. You have to enable 'withCredentials' on the client's request as well. I also think you DON'T need `if('OPTIONS' == req.method)` as I've never needed this. One more note, you can't use a wildcard domain '*' with credentials. You'd have to explicitly allow origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' and make sure you're cookie uses the 127 and not localhost (you'll run into problems with cookies otherwise).

```
     var req = {
                    method:'POST',
                    url: 'users/login',
                    data: {
                    },
                    withCredentials:true

                };

                $http(req).then(function (response) {                       
                    if( response.data.success ){                           
                    }
                    if( response.data.error){                           
                    }
                });
```